# How to preserve Image Quality when rotating with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Basically I'm trying to be able to rotate images via user interface, however I've noticed that the image quality severely decreases upon each rotation. Does anyone know how to fix that? Also when the image is rotated it crops off parts of the image each time.

here are some pictures
of before and after:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5WVJ.jpg

And here's the code:

```
def onRotate(self):
    tanTheta = float(hh)/float(ww) 
    theta = math.atan(tanTheta) * 57.2957795 # convert to degrees
    if theta > 0:
        angle = (90 - theta) * -1
        clockwise = True
    elif theta < 0:
        angle = (270 - theta) * -1
        clockwise = False
    else:
        tkMessageBox('Angle not okay', 'Try again!')
    rotated_small = photo_small.rotate(angle) 
    rotated_small.save('small_rotate.jpg')
    self.load_imgfile('small_rotate.jpg')
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
rotated_small = photo_small.rotate(angle, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)
```

This tells it to use the highest quality interpolation algorithm that it has available, and to expand the image to encompass the full rotated size instead of cropping. The documentation does not say what color the background will be filled with.

Comment: So I think instead of filter=Image.BICUBIC, it's supposed to be resample=Image.BICUBIC . but this definitely worked! Thanks!!

Comment: @user2525507 the documentation I used at http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm appears to be in error. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @MarkRansom  hmmm.  this is not working for me.   any ideas what I can look at as to why it is not working?

Comment: @DanielGoldfarb you need to specify which version of Python and PIL or Pillow. Then you need to be more specific about what "not working" means. That would be better done by asking a new question - you can point back to this one if you want.

Comment: @MarkRansom  Thanks.  Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59504849/

Answer (score 7):

An image is a grid of pixels. If you rotate it (and angle isn't a multiple of 90) the rotated grid must be rematched to a new non-rotated grid to display the image. Some loss can't be avoided in this process.

Only option would be to keep the unrotated image somewhere and sum up the angles of multiple rotations and always build the rotated image from the initial unrotated one.

Comment: and could you please translate this gibberish to some code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are rotating jpegs at 90 degree increments you want to use JPEGTran, which will do lossless rotation:

- https://jpegtran-cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api-reference
- https://pypi.org/project/jpegtran-cffi/

See `rotate()` and `exif_autotransform()`.  A CLI may be easier:

- `sudo apt install libjpeg-turbo-progs`

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in doing a 90° rotation, then you can use a `transpose` instead of a rotate`. That will better, if not 100%, preserve quality. If you have a PIL image called` img`, you can transpose like this:

```py
img.transpose(PIL.Image.ROTATE_90)
```

Side note: convert from radians to degrees by using `math.degrees(my_radians)` instead of multiplying by 57.2957795; i.e. `math.degrees(math.atan(tanTheta))`