# PIL image.rotate with transparency

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, transparency

Is there any way to rotate RGBA image, that the result will be smoother. [image]

I mean, the bottom stop sign is the original image, the top is rotate by (PIL):

```
img.rotate(angle)
```

Is there other build in function for it?

Comment: Did you try : img.rotate(angle, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True). 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17821945/how-to-preserve-image-quality-when-rotating-with-pil

Comment: try `cv2.warpAffine()`, see links: https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html   https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html

Comment: Thanks @user8190410 but I don't want to convert it to cv.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

top left:

```
img.rotate(angle, resample=Image.BILINEAR, expand=True)
```

top right:

```
img.rotate(angle, resample=Image.BICUBIC, expand=True)
```

bottom original.

based on @Dinesh comment